# fgets to read serial port

Tags: serial-port, fgets

I am using `fgets` to read serially. Is there a way to break from `fgets` if nothing is received rather than keep on waiting for a serial character?

I have: `new_command=getserial();`

Where `getserial` is the function using `fgets`.

This is in a while loop with other tasks. I would like the program to still continue its execution if no serial character is received and if a serial character is received, I would like to break from the while loop using break. At the moment the program will only continue its execution of while loop if a serial character is received.

My code is something on these lines:

```
while (condition not satisfied)

{

new_command=getserial();

  If (new_command == 0)

  {

  printf("Hello");

  }

  else
  {
     break;
  }
}
```

So in my case I would like to print hello if no serial character is received. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Serial ports normally support specifying a read timeout to prevent endless blocking.  Hard to guess what you are using without any OS or library hint in the question so you make it too difficult to give specific advice.

Comment: please provide the minimum source code that enables others to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I used select () to timeout the serial port. Code below.

```
fd_set read_fds, write_fds, except_fds;
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
FD_ZERO(&except_fds);
FD_SET(fd, &read_fds);

// Set timeout to 1.0 seconds
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 1;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

// Wait for input to become ready or until the time out

bytesRead=select(fd + 1, &read_fds, &write_fds, &except_fds, &timeout);

if (bytesRead == 1)
{
    if (fgets(buf , sizeof(buf) , stdin) != NULL)
    {
        //printf("It is ready for reading");

    }
}
else
{
printf("Timeout Error\n");

}
```